# Insecure HTTP Methods Enabled - How to disable

Tags: apache, security

We are running rational app scan on our app URL and it comes back with the following result:

It seems that the 
web server is configured to allow one (or more) of the following HTTP methods 
(verbs)
- DELETE
- SEARCH
- COPY
- MOVE
- PROPFIND
- PROPPATCH
- MKCOL
- LOCK
- UNLOCK
- PUT

To fix this I added a RewriteRule to forbid any of these methods. Now when I test manually I get response code 403:

```
curl -X PUT https://someurl.com/somecontext/somepage.xhtml

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /somecontext/somepage.xhtml
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

But rational app scan still shows this as a problem. Has anyone encountered the same problem. This URL goes to a tomcat backend via AJP. Would appreciate solution for this.

PS: I had Limit and LimitExcept in mind but I am not sure if it will block the requests that go via mod_proxy or mod_jk

Comment: Got Subversion or DAV isntalled?

Comment: that was my first reaction but no. Its disabled

Comment: I'll share my answer about using mod_allowmethods here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77702864/936752

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simple solution that worked in the end

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]
```

This keeps the app scan happy (and me as well)

Comment: Is it in the httpd.conf?

Comment: yes, its in httpd.conf. If you have vhosts configured then inside the required vhost

Comment: I don't like simple solutions which are adding 3 extra regex comparisons per single request.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect Apache is forwarding the OPTIONS request (which fetches a list of potentially-supported methods) to Tomcat. You then get the default HttpServlet implementation of [`doOptions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doOptions%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29), which apparently returns an `Allow` header with `TRACE` in it.

You could override `doOptions` to remove `TRACE` from this misleading list, eg to match Apache:

```
response.setHeader("Allow", "OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST");
```

Or, you could just block OPTIONS wholly if you're sure you won't ever need any of its other features (eg CORS pre-flighting). Incidentally, you could also use [Limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limit) together with mod_access to restrict access to desired methods, rather than have to drag in the mod_rewrite processing chain.

Or: if you are sure that you don't actually have `TRACE` or any other unwanted methods available, you could just ignore the finding. AppScan is trying to warn you that it *looks like* there *might* be some dangerous methods available, but it hasn't actually found a vulnerability as such. Having `OPTIONS` return methods that don't actually work is undesirable, but it's not a real security problem.

Answer (score 6):

We initially set below conf in httpd.conf in Apache to disable vulnerable HTTP methods[TRACE|TRACK|PUT|DELETE|CONNECT|OPTIONS] and it didn't work for us:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|PUT|DELETE|CONNECT|OPTIONS)

    RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Now, we have set below rule and its working:

```
 Order allow,deny

 Allow from all

 <LimitExcept POST GET>

       Deny from all

 </LimitExcept>
```

Comment: Looks really good, and avoids the slow and quirky mod_rewrite. Has anyone here tested this? It will be a good general solution someday when browsers all supply the scheme "https://" by default, so http won't happen except in situations where there should be an error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think AppScan, and all scanners for that matter,  uses the OPTIONS directive to find out the enabled methods. You probably need to add that on your rewrite rule.

The best way would be thought to go over your documentation and disable these methods altogether.

Cheers,
Zach

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work. I added this to config:  
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)  
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]  

This is giving better results. Lets see if app scan passes this.