# Disable OPTIONS HTTP on Apache Server

Tags: java, apache, jboss

```
Request:
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: webcat.staci.com
Connection: Keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21
Accept: */*

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 12:24:59 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=7, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: httpd/unix-directory
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerwebcat-ssl=192938503.47873.0000; path=/; httponly; secure
```

i want to disable HTTP OPTIONS on my Apache Server but i want to keep `GET`, `POST` and i want to `PING` my server.

how could I do that ?

***my httpd.conf:***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^ (GET,POST,HEAD)
RewriteRule .* – [R=405,L]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Putting `Disable OPTIONS HTTP on Apache Server` in Google returns on top https://sureshk37.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/how-to-disable-apache-http-options-method/.

Comment: Dear gentlemen, if you downvote please give at least a small comment how my answer can be improved.

Comment: Did you follow the link I posted? You would have found the same solution posted by Stefano. Seems the answer was not hidden in the internet. ;-)

Comment: @SubOptimal i follow the link but he doesn't talk about `ping`

Comment: Maybe add more information what you tried, what you expect and what you get instead. What do you mean with `you want to PING your server`? Something like `ping your.server.ip`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OPTIONS method cannot be disabled using RewriteCond.
You must disabled by using LimitExcept directive.

Below is the snippet could be added on outside of the  of the Apache configuration:

```
<Location />
    <LimitExcept GET POST>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Please do not forget to re-start the web server :)

Comment: Your solution also disables the `ping` ?

Comment: No, the ping is disable only if you use  "Disable HTTP Methods Rewrite Rule"

Comment: This doesn't work on a WordPress site. I have the recommended configuration in my Apache configuration, but the WordPress .htaccess overrides it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570860/apache-mod-rewrite-to-block-html-options-requests-with-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to apply it to a particular project:

Simply adding these lines to an `.htaccess` file worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(OPTIONS)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

For this to work, make sure you have enabled the `mod_rewrite` and that you use `RewriteEngine On` before these lines.

Comment: This recommendation works, but not in conjunction with WordPress automatically added directives. See this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570860/apache-mod-rewrite-to-block-html-options-requests-with-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

To disable the **HTTP OPTIONS** method on your `Apache server` while still allow **GET**, **POST**, and **PING** requests, you can use the following configuration in your **httpd.conf file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS$
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]

<LocationMatch "/your_ping_endpoint">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</LocationMatch>
```

Replace `/your_ping_endpoint` with the actual **URL** endpoint you want to use for **PING** requests. This configuration will return a **405** (**Method not allowed**) response for any **OPTIONS** requests and deny access to the `your_ping_endpoint` **URL** from anywhere except **localhost** (**127.0.0.1**).

Additionally, make sure to enable the rewrite module in Apache by running the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

After making these changes, restart your Apache server for the configuration to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't like with all these `RewriteCond` solutions that it adds extra regexp calculations for every request.

Problem with `<Limit` or `<LimitExcept` that it returns 403 and default welcome page.

One of the simple solutions what I have found, is this:

```
<Location />
    AllowMethods GET POST PUT DELETE
</Location>
```

Put it outside of your `<VirtualHost/>` directive and thats it.
Only one big not, this feature is marked **Experimental** since Apache 2.3

See docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html