# Apache mod_rewrite to block HTTP OPTIONS requests, with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a working mod_rewrite cond/rule in my .htaccess which stops HTTP OPTIONS requests perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I also have in Apache configuration (for belt and braces):

```
<Location />
    <LimitExcept GET POST>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

As advised as the top answer here: [Disable OPTIONS HTTP on Apache Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599883/disable-options-http-on-apache-server)

However, WordPress adds the following to the same .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And in doing so kills my HTTP OPTIONS killer as can been seen in a response to this request:

```
> curl -i -X OPTIONS https://www.MYWEBSITE.co.uk/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
....
```

I've tried combining the two mod_rewrite rules in a multitude of combinations. I either get 500s, or the WordPress site works fine and OPTIONS requests are honoured.

How can I have the WordPress site work fine and at the same time issue a deny response to HTTP OPTIONS requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that by adding the following above the WordPress HTACCESS directives resolved the issue:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(POST|GET)\ /.*\ HTTP/1\.1$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I found this recommendation here:
https://protonts.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/how-to-disable-http-options-method/

I'm not at this stage clear why the above worked when the following did *not* work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```